# Which Purana gives the Chandikeshwara story?

Tags: shiva

There is a popular story of Chandikeshwara told as stated in the Periya Puranam (Tamil): See here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-reason-people-clap-to-Chandikeshwar-in-Shiva-Temple

There is also a Telugu depiction in YouTube here: https://youtu.be/_xZ426ExUAs

I would like to know which Purana (of the 18 Mahapuranas or 18 Upapuranas) have this story of Chandikeshwara.